# Distribution outside of the Mac App Store: Please remove prefix "Developer ID Application:"

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store

I'd like to build `dmg` target to distribute app outside of App Store.

I've read the documentation:

- https://www.electron.build/code-signing
- Notarize app for macOS https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3870
- https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

My config:

```
  "build": {
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ],
    },
  }
```

I'm using the following command:

```sh
 CSC_NAME="Developer ID Application: Company Name (12345)" electron-builder --mac
```

I've faced with the following error: `⨯ Please remove prefix "Developer ID Application:" from the specified name — appropriate certificate will be chosen automatically`

According to the Apple documentation I must use `Developer ID certificate` https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

If I've removed `Developer ID Application:` from `CSC_NAME` then `Apple Distribution: Company Name (12345)` was chosen.

How should I specify a certificate name to get around the error above and build `outside of App Store dmg` with the correct certificate to be able to notarize the app?

* **Version**: 22.6.0

* **Electron Version**: 8.2.5
* **Electron Type (current, beta, nightly)**: current

* **Target**: dmg (Distribution outside of the Mac App Store)

Question in Github: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4935

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions [here](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2019/electron/notarizing-your-electron-application/)? These instructions are linked in the `electron-builder` docs for signing & notarizing apps for macOS.

You should be using a .env file with two values: `APPLE_ID` and `APPLE_NOTARIZE_PW`, which are used in the notarization script that's in the instructions. These instructions work for me, and I'm not using any parameter named `CSC_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this issue cost me considerable amount of time and I mostly felt helpless until I eventually figured out the solution. This should probably work for everyone who face this issue.

When I renewed my Apple Developer membership, I found I already had two certificates under my account, so I downloaded those and added them to my Keychain. However, Electron-builder refused to pick them up during app packaging. It always picked other irrelevant certificates instead.

What I then did was to [create new certificates](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-developer-id-certificates/) and downloaded those. Once I added them to Keychain, and re-ran Electron-builder, it immediately picked them up and signed my app correctly.

What was the difference between these new certificates and the old ones? Well, one prominent thing is that these new certificates contained their `private key` (just as [mentioned](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4935#issuecomment-846311686) by a user on GitHub).

So it must mean the first two certificates I had downloaded were created with my old computer (some years back) and so their private keys were not present when I downloaded them from devevloper.apple.com. When creating the new certs, the Form prompts you to link a `certificate singing request file` (don't worry it's all in the instructions from the first link I shared), which I believe contains the missing private key that my older certificates didn't have.

### --

***Side Note (This next bit is slightly unrelated):***

When Electron-builder successfully picks your certs and attempts to sign your App, you maybe prompted to enter the key password to allow the signing. In my case, I had no idea what the password would be (computer password didn't work), so I instead:

1. went to Keychain
2. expand the certificate to view the private key
3. right click on the private key
4. click "Get Info"
5. a small pop-up will appear with an "Access Control" tab, click the "Access Control" tab and select "Allow all apps access this item"
6. click save
7. it will prompt you for a password but your computer password will work in this case.
8. Once that's done, you can run Electron-builder again.
9. Of course you can go back to undo this setting once your application is done packaging.